# VLC Media Server

Tags: ubuntu, media, video

We are using VLC on ubuntu, and trying to set up a streaming media server. We have the http interface working fine from remote computers, and we can also see the video playing as text if we don't screen VLC. Our problem is the output streaming. When we use the main VLC page you get when you goto the servers IP it does not save the output MRL (refreshing page it will go away, even after clicking save.) We tried to VLM page and it appears to work fine from the http page (it buffers, plays, timers go up when not paused, etc.) However, we still cannot connect remotely with a VLC client. The output parameters do save properly on the VLM page. We are noobs when it comes to this.

**Does anyone have a very to the point procedure of getting a file X to play and stream on ubuntu using VLC assuming VLC is installed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another alternative to consider, have you ever considered using something like *mediatomb* for your media serving needs? It is a UPnP/DLNA capable media server. You can integrate VLC to do transcoding work if necessary.